# How to run typescript locally when i have it globally?

Tags: typescript

I have the `typescript` globally, and when i run `tsc -v` in any directory it gives me `Version 3.2.2`.

But, now i have an application which i have installed `typescript` ***locally***. 
In my `package.json` i have `"typescript": "^3.3.3"`. Therefore, my local `tsc` is updater than the global one.

When i navigate to the `node_modules\typescript\bin`, and run `tsc -v` in this folder, it still gives me `Version 3.2.2`. So, i suppose, it is still using the ***global*** version.

I am wondering, how may i force it to use my local `tsc` file?

i navigated to `node_modules\.bin` and then `tsc -v` and it complains with:

```
bash: tsc: command not found
```

Comment: Try: `node_modules\.bin\tsc`.

Comment: @Paleo did not work. please check my updated question.

Comment: did you try `npx tsc -v` inside project directory?

Comment: @ttomalak no, i don't know what is it. let me give it a try

Comment: For the manual solution (without `npx`) there is maybe an extension `.cmd` under Windows? Try: `node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd`.

Comment: @ttomalak it perfectly worked for me. Would you like to write it as an answer, and then i will accept it?

Comment: @Paleo thanks, the `npx` is very helpful.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara `npx` is nice but if you forget to navigate to the project directory it will install and use `tsc` from a central cache. The best solution remain to add a script in your `package.json`: `"scripts": {"build": "tsc"}`, then to run it with: `npm run build`.

Answer (score -2):

To run project specified typescript version, you can use builtin npm commnad `npx`. Just run

`npx tsc -v`

from your project directory